# Angular animate does not function correctly when you have predefined css state in addition to the transition state

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation, ng-animate

Consider the following css

```
            /* starting animations */
            .error-animation.ng-enter {

                -webkit-transition: 0.5s linear all;
                transition: 0.5s linear all;

                opacity: 0;
            }

            /* destination animations */
            .error-animation.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
                opacity: 0.7;
            }


            #my-error {
                color: red;
                margin-left: 10px;
                margin-top: 10px;
                opacity: 0.7
            }
```

If my html element contains the animation class and custom id that have the same feature. The transition will not work for that feature.

```
            <div id="my-error" 
                 ng-if="error" ng-cloak class="error-animation">
                Error
            </div>
```

In the above code the feature causing the problem is `opacity`

My `ng-enter` state have `opacity: 0`

My `ng-enter-active` state have `opacity: 0.7`

My default state have `opacity: 0.7`

Because the default state is more specific than the ng-animate class, it will override it (the animation will not work).

However the dilemma is that even if I got rid of `opacity:0.7` in the default state, it will assume default opacity is `1` and transition first from `0` to `0.7` and `0.7` to `1`.

Can someone give me some insight in solving this problem?

Here is a quick example to play [with](http://plnkr.co/edit/3MxjT9l3OQInrH8ZTYbx?p=preview)

Comment: Did this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

If the element has defined a default opacity itself, do you want this to be used? Or do you want the opacity from the error animation to always take precedence?

You can add `!important` in the animation hidden state:

```
.fade-in-out.ng-hide {
  opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

You will then get the following behavior.

- If the element has no opacity defined it will be animated from 0 to 0.7, and from 0.7 to 0.
- If the element has for example 0.4 opacity defined it will be animated from 0 to 0.4, and 0.4 to 0.

If you add `!important` in the animation shown state as well, the elements own opacity will be ignored and 0.7 will always take precedence:

```
.fade-in-out {
  transition: 1s linear all;
  opacity: 0.7 !important;
}
```